# return statement in a for looop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, return

It is said that "RETURN" statement terminates a for loop in javascript but in this case the code will still output 3 why? does that mean the return statement doesn't terminate the loop?

```js
var printNumTwo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

Comment: Because the for loop will break when `i === 3` and that's why the fuction return 3;

Comment: When `i===2` you define a function that returns `i`, whatever its value. Very well. Then the loops keeps going. Now `i===3`, the loop is over, that part is done. Now you execute `printNumTwo()` when `i===3`, so it outputs `3`. The `return` statement is _not_ in your `for` loop. It is inside a function defined inside your `for` loop.

Comment: `return` doesn’t specifically terminate a loop; it terminates the closest containing function. If `return` _happens_ to be in a loop, which is inside the function being terminated, then `return` terminates the function in the middle of the loop. Your function being terminated is `printNumTwo`. You only execute this function after the loop is done. The `return` doesn’t touch your loop.

Comment: As pointed out in the answers, there’s an orthogonal problem going on: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](/q/750486/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

[@jeremy-thille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille) explained how the loop continues and `i` becomes 3. Additionally, this occurs, because `i` is not scoped within the loop. If you use `let` to assign `i`, it is scoped within the loop ([block-scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)), and the result would be as expected.

```js
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = () => i;
  }
}

console.log(printNumTwo());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add console.log to understand. Since, `printNumTwo = function(){}` is definition of function not execution. You can try other example:

```
var printNumTwo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log('before', i);
   printNumTwo = function() {
      console.log('end', i);
      return i;
    };
  if (i === 2) {
    console.log('process', i);
  };
  console.log('after', i);
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
/* ouput
> "before" 0
> "after" 0
> "before" 1
> "after" 1
> "before" 2
> "process" 2
> "after" 2
> "end" 3
> 3
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `i` variable in for loop with the `var` keyword. `var` has function scope and due to this when the `for` loop runs, `i` will be increased to 3 and then it will check for condition and exit the for loop but it will be assigned value 3 to `i` in the global scope.

To get 2 as the output you have to define `i` with the `let` keyword that has block scope and the last fetched value will be provided when the function runs.

```js
var printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    } 
  }
}
 console.log(printNumTwo());
```

Comment: This is painful to read; could you please edit your answer, add capital letters and punctuation (commas, etc.)?